# Repr of lxml node

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, repr

Is there a way to customize how an etree node appears for debugging purposes? It seems to give its memory address by default:

```
[<Element edition at 0x10dd2e998>, <Element edition at 0x10dd2ed40>, <Element edition at 0x10dd2eea8>, <Element edition at 0x10dd2ec20>, <Element edition at 0x10dd2ec68>]
```

I'm guessing the `repr` is something like:

```
f'<Elemement {tagName} at 0x{memoryAddress}>'
```

I would like to change it to something like:

```
f'<Element {tagName} with language={language}>'
```

How can I do that? Here's a basic example:

```
from lxml import etree
xml_str='''<editions><edition language="English">en.wiktionary.org</edition><edition language="French">fr.wiktionary.org</edition></editions>'''
etree.fromstring(xml_str).xpath('//edition')
# [<Element edition at 0x10dd2ed40>, <Element edition at 0x10dd2eea8>]
```

I want it to be:

```
# [<Element edition with language=English>, ...]
```

Comment: `__repr__` is defined in a Cython module: https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/etree.pyx#L1121. I don't know if it's possible to customize.

Comment: It will be hard to get `etree` to use a derived `Element` class you could give a new `__repr__` function. Just monkey-patching in a different `__repr__` for Element also is definitely not the way to go. You could just create a function that takes the value and returns a pretty-printed string representation like the one you need though.